# Confusion about "weight" hyperparameter for SVM using ´mlr` in R

Tags: svm

I am building on top of [a publication](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8821368) that employs a binary SVM classifier.

They report they use the `mlr` R package. Some research says that this basically uses the implementation of the `e1071` package ([docs can be found here](https://rdrr.io/cran/e1071/man/svm.html)).

Now, in the paper, they mention a "weight" hyperparameter and I am at a loss what that is supposed to be. I have never heard about it in the context of SVMs and cannot find it in any documentation.

The only thing that comes to mind are class weights for handling unbalanced class sizes -- indeed, the dataset under consideration is imbalanced. However, that should not be a single number, or at least they should have mentioned *which* class receives that single number as a weight.

Would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class that is ocurring way more often then the other class you can prioritize one class. You use weights to do this.

Here the implementation for randomforest:

```
rf3 <- randomForest(geklaut ~ ., Originaldaten[2000001:2227502,] classwt=   c(0.561159327 , 4.641041406))
```

Here for package mlr (there is a second implementation in tuning as a hyperparameter):

```
rlearn_lm <- makeWeightedClassesWrapper(makeLearner("classif.randomForest"),     wcw.weight = 0.1209123724417812)
```

for more info on usage google the methods